# Mongoose $in not working on using variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use the $in operator, and I have the code as is shown below:

```
var list = []
for(var x=0; x<board.members.length; x++) {
  list.push(new ObjectId(board.members[x].toHexString()));
}    
return User.find({_id: { $in: list}}).exec();
```

Even though I have two items in my list array, the result set only contains one item. However, if I construct the same query as follows:

```
return User.find({_id: { $in: [new ObjectId("5603d450951764890c6d013d"), new ObjectId("5603d450951764890c6d013f")]}}).exec();
```

then the result set contains the two items that I expect. I am not sure why on using the list variable, I am not able to retrieve the correct data. Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have also tried using the $in operator as is shown below and I still get one item back:

```
return User.find({_id: { $in: board.members}}).exec();
```

Comment: Why all the looping an existing array and `.toHexString()` or even `ObjectId()` malarkey? If the input is already an array of strings that are valid for an `ObjectId` value, then mongoose will just automatically cast them as such for you. `User.find({ "_id": { "$in": board.members } },function(err,results) { ... })` should work just fine if that is the case.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: I have tried what you suggested previously, but it does the same as in the example above. I reached the above state of code by trying out different ways in which I could get this query to work.

Comment: How about editing your question to show exactly what you have "tried". Your mistakes are clearly in the implementation, and the code you have submitted to date is likely to fail for a number of reasons with incorrect input. If just do what I said then it works fine ( you are not the first person to do this or ask by a long way ), but if you still are not sure, then post the other code attempts along this line and we can point out the errrors, and the correct approach.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I have tried implementing it the way you have suggested and it does not work. There is no other things I have "tried". I would really appreciate your help if you knew why it would be failing, given that I have implemented it the way you suggest to.